# Saving 3-channel image when each channel is the same (python)

Tags: python, opencv

I have a three channel image composed of 3 identical grayscale, 8-bit images.  I'm just doing this so I can accommodate a neural network size requirement.  I open the image using open-cv, and verify it is three channel, but when I save it the image is single channel 8-bit

```
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, f), -1).astype(np.uint8)
print(img.shape)
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, f), img)
```

img.shape here is (5,5,3), but the resultant saved image is (5,5) 8-bit.  I'm unsure if this is an issue with linux, opencv, etc.  I suspect there's some sort of auto compression happening, but that shouldn't be the case.  I've tried saving with opencv and with skimage but cannot get either to save a RGB image.

Comment: Confirmed that the image is just being auto-compressed into one channel because of information redundancy.  If I create a new image with two zero value channels and one data channel it saves as RGB.  Not sure if opencv does this or if linux does?

Comment: Please post a reproducible code sample. Please describe the way you are testing the number of channels of the "resultant saved image".

Comment: Nothing outside cv has any idea what the data is or how to remove channels. cv will only remove channels if you call something like flat or reshape.  Please show a [mre]

Comment: please state the file type. [mre] requires no unknowns.

Comment: Can you please try img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, f), -1) and img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, f)) ? Can you upload the image file?

Comment: How do you know (measure) that the result is (5,5) 8-bit?  What tool?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Python/OpenCV

- Read the color input
- Convert to grayscale
- Merge to 3 equal channel image
- Print the shape
- Save the 3 equal channel image
- Read the 3 equal channel image unchanged
- Print the shape

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image 
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# convert to 3 equal channels
gray3 = cv2.merge([gray,gray,gray])

print(gray3.shape)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('gray_3channel.jpg', gray3)

# read result unchanged
img2 = cv2.imread('gray_3channel.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

print(img2.shape)
```

Resulting 3 channel image:

[image]

Shape:

```
(256, 256, 3) -- merged 3 equal channels
(256, 256, 3) -- saved and read unchanged image
```